# MS Access Reference to LATEST Excel/Word/etc

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I haven't seen this exact question yet:

I have multiple installations of MS Office (don't ask, just need it!).  Anyway, I've developed a database that will create and interact with Excel sheets and Word documents. Currently, when creating these files, I'm using something like `Excel.14` or `Word.14` to specify Office 2010 documents.  We are upgrading to Office 2013, and though I will still have Office 2010 installed, I want VBA to point to `Word.15` but I don't want to hard code it.

I don't want to edit the code each time we upgrade.  Is there a way to ensure that these references will ALWAYS pick the latest version of installed software?

Thanks for the help!

...Scotty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use *late binding* to achieve this. Instead of setting a Reference in the project and using...

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
```

...you could try omitting the project Reference and use

```
Dim objExcel As Object, objWord As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Comment: +1 for late binding.  RE *latest* application version, I would try `CreateObject("Excel.Application.15")`.  If that throws error #429, *"ActiveX component can't create object"*, try ``CreateObject("Excel.Application.14")` ... and so forth.  But it would be easier to just late bind and not have to worry about the *latest* version.  :-)

Comment: Ok, will try that.  I'll also make sure I'm only adding 'references' to the latest ms office objects.  That should force it too.  Thanks!